# SQL solution to handle the order of cells in Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have a flat file with a lot of columns and I need it to imported to a database through Toad, so I spent all morning to create manually the table, before to import the file., but the person who extract the data from another database told me that he sent me the same file with correct data in each columns, because the first file have in some places strange characters /@! etc.

Well when I open the file I realize that the order of columns is not the same like in first file that he send me and in which I have based to build the table!

I mean when I try to upload the file the columns intersect the whole data!

So, the first way is to change the whole structure of the table.

```
     ID   INTEGER            NOT NULL,
     NAME VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
etc ..+250 rows
```

but it takes too long ..

The another option is to drag the cells:

[image]

I am sure that exist a better solution that already I know., for example recognize the columns by name and make the change in a few steps and not waste all day in something that simple!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Right Click on the table name in Schema Browser, and you'll find the import data option. I don't have Toad now, but I am almost sure there is a better way to organize columns with Toad importer.

However, Toad importer seemed slow to me.

Comment: The only way to import a flat file through Toad is ->Database->Import and then you need to choose the table and click view the table and show you the order of the columns, but the order of the cells in flat file is different., so i need to change the order of the columns in Toad to be exactly in the order of the flat file and this must be done before you get to import the data file. What sw you use?., i mean that you told me Toad is not good enough

Comment: I don't know if is the same thing as I know. There should be a check that first row contains header, so it will identify names of columns.

Comment: I'm almost pretty sure that no exist that check which you refer

Comment: I will look later to see if have this options., but anyway i want to know if Toad have any solution to my problem as i work daily with this tool., and  honestly i do not like the SQL-Dev is very SLOW and missing many features that Toad have them .. for that reason I'm sure that he have tricky hide this option.